# Connect to Redis using rejson client in python using url

Tags: python, redis, connection, client

I want to connect to remote REDIS client using rejson but cant quite get my Client right.

Here is what I am using:

```
rj = Client(host='rediss://redis-REDACTED.aivencloud.com', port=15381, username='REDACTED', password='REDACTED', decode_responses=True)
```

But I get this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

This approach works great just using the regular redis module.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's working for you, with redis-py? can you try `Client(host='rediss://redis-REDACTED.aivencloud.com:15381', username='REDACTED', password='REDACTED', decode_responses=True)
`

Comment: SSL connection https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#ssl-connections